# Java newbie. Using the Math class

Tags: java, max, min

I am writing a piece of code that allows users to enter test scores.  I then need to use the Math.max and Math.min to keep track of max and min and display the answer.  I am not sure where I type that code or how I type that code.

Please let me know what pieces of the code would be helpful to post! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the code you have tried

Comment: Where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: I actually just got it to work.

Comment: I had the min and max numbers set incorrectly.  min=0 max=999

Answer (score 3):

Start by breaking down the problem into steps and figure out what you need to know. In your case you need to know four things:

1. How to get input from the console
2. How to compare values
3. How to conditionally change values
4. How to display things to the console

One and four you can search up pretty easy. Look into "Hello world" and other such starter programs for Java. Two and three you should look up "if" statements for Java. Hope this sets you on the right track.

Comment: Looks like a helpful pointer, tells the asker where to start but doesn't tell them how to do something. Another thing that might need to be more explicit: Look it up. Type your problem into google.